# Does the Booming Blade cantrip's secondary damage trigger only when the creature moves locations?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, cantrips

The description of the *booming blade* cantrip says (SCAG, p. 142; emphasis mine):

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee
>   attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range,
>   otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack's
>   normal effects, and it becomes sheathed in booming energy until the
>   start of your next turn. **If the target willingly moves before then**,
>   it immediately takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends.

Does "moves" refer to moving from one location to another, or is it any action that would require movement (e.g. attacking or using items, etc.)?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see also: [Does standing up from prone trigger the secondary damage from the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73552/does-standing-up-from-prone-trigger-the-secondary-damage-from-the-booming-blade)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Rules designer Jeremy Crawford unofficially clarified via Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/659436991956799488) that it refers to using your movement, as in "I move X feet" - not a generic "move", as in "I scratch my nose":

> When booming blade refers to moving, it means movement in the game's normal sense: moving X feet.

Moreover, standing from prone, while it uses movement, does not count as a move for the *booming blade* spell, as [Crawford has also clarified](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/663030224154562561):

> Standing up costs movement but moves you nowhere. To move while prone, you crawl or use magic (PH, 191).

Comment: One thing to note as well with this is that the movement of the target has to be of their own conviction, forced movement doesn't work.