# Are there any official rules for the exact meaning of the phrase "when the target willingly moves" in Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, cantrips, forced-movement

The Booming Blade cantrip's secondary effect states that "[the target] becomes sheathed in booming energy until the start of your next turn. If the target willingly moves before then, it immediately takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends". We can deduce, then:

- That the damage does not trigger when the target is dragged or pushed around via physical means (grappling, shoving, scenario effects, etc.)
- That the damage does not trigger when the target is dragged or pushed around via magical means (Gust, Eldritch Blast with Grasp of Hadar, Graviturgist's Gravity Well, etc.)

This seems pretty clear. However, what happens when the following cases arise?

- The target is ordered to move via the use of Command (assuming they don't know yet that the thunderous aura is damaging).
- The target is forced to move via the use of Compulsion.
- The target is invited to move via the use of Suggestion.
- The target is Turned.
- The target is Frightened and forced to run via Dissonant Whispers.
- The target has a Geas that prohibits them from ending a turn next to an enemy if they can avoid it.
- The target is threatened into leaving the area or else. This one seems "willingly", but are they truly willing if they are panicking because you are telling them you will cut their heads off if they don't run?

[This tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/703385127582171138) seems to suggest that forcing people to move via mind control spells doesn't count as willing. However, [after the release of the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium, Jeremy Crawford's Twitter rulings are no longer considered official](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi), so I was looking for something more solid to make a RAW judgement of this interaction.

Comment: I was actually looking for some official ruling or errata on the matter. The question you linked cites Jeremy Crawford's Tweet, which, after the release of 2019's Sage Advice Compendium, it is no longer considered official.

Comment: A different answer from this question: [Can I trigger an Opportunity Attack by forcing an opponent to move out of my reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120959/can-i-trigger-an-opportunity-attack-by-forcing-an-opponent-to-move-out-of-my-rea)

Comment: Related/Duplicate: "[What counts as willing movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139940)" and "[Would a frightened, fleeing creature be considered moving willingly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114650)" and "[Does the movement from Infestation count as willing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124904)" and questions on [*booming blade* and standing from prone](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73552) and [*booming blade* and teleporting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122943) and [*booming blade* and moving without changing your location](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94072)

Comment: Related on [What defines willing? Can you make an unwilling creature willing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/can-you-make-an-unwilling-creature-willing-in-other-words-what-defines-willin)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Currently, your question has been closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139940) and also [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114650). In other words, people believe that your question is asking effectively the same thing as those other two. If you feel this is *not* the case or that there is something found only in your question and not the others, feel free to [edit] your question or leave a comment explaining why. Your question can *always* be reopened. Best of luck and happy gaming!

Comment: I would like to reopen the question as the first one quotes a Jeremy Crawford Tweet, which is not RAW, and the second one makes an assumption about the workings of charm effects. Neither actually solve what happens when a target is non-magically panicking. Non-magic panic isn't a RAW mechanic, but many DM use it. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/can-you-make-an-unwilling-creature-willing-in-other-words-what-defines-willin) also seems to suggest that you may force a creature to be willing via mind control, so the answer isn't as crystal clear.

Comment: Not to mention that [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139940/what-counts-as-willing-movement) also suggests that some forms of mind control that indirectly force an enemy to move do count, so the exact RAW definition of "willing" is not clear.

Comment: @Blacktay Unfortunately, the question remains a duplicate because the questions are the same. Typically, the proper step is to bounty that question for what you're looking for. But you are new and don't have a lot of rep to give up, so I've done the bounty on that question.

Comment: @NautArch Thanks for the Bounty. Appreciated.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know of any specific rules in the DnD rulebooks which state that in particular, and I don't think there would be. In the case of defining words or interpreting rules, that's totally up to the DM. They should be deciding if movement while turned etc. counts as "willing" based on what they think is fair and makes sense, same with any other discrepancies you may encounter.