# Do Tabaxi regain the use of their Feline Agility trait if they get up from being knocked prone but don't move to a different space?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, racial-traits, prone, tabaxi

If a Tabaxi PC is knocked prone and then uses their turn to get up without moving anywhere else, does that let them refresh their Feline Agility racial ability?

Getting up uses half their movement speed, but they don't actually move anywhere.

Comment: Related: "[Does standing up from prone trigger the secondary damage from the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73552)"

Comment: @Medix2 Thanks for the reference! I found [the answer with Crawford's ruling that getting up from being prone doesn't count as moving](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94098/8838) to be especially useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Getting up from prone uses movement, but is not the same as moving.

The [Tabaxi's Feline Agility trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tabaxi#TabaxiTraits) states (VGtM, p. 115):

> Once you use this trait, you can’t use it again until you move 0 feet on one of your turns.

While standing up from [prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BeingProne) uses some of your movement, it is never described as "moving":

> You can drop prone without using any of your speed. Standing up takes more effort; doing so costs an amount of movement equal to half your speed.

All other uses of your [movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) are described as moving:

> Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These different modes of movement can be combined with walking, or they can constitute your entire move. **However you're *moving*, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.**

I've emphasized the crucial bit: *moving involves distance travelled, which is deducted from your remaining movement appropriately.* This deduction of movement is mechanically distinct from the deduction of movement for standing up from prone.

**Conclusion**: You can use Feline Agility after a turn where the only movement deducted was from standing up from prone.